# Xamarin.android not loading from Production in Play Store

Tags: android, xamarin.android, google-play

I have an app written in Xamarin.android that is having issues when uploading to the production channel in Play Store.

From time to time, when the application is uploaded to production it just breaks.

The last version we uploaded a new version, we uploaded it to the Beta channel in the Play Store Console, it worked without any problems, and when we sent it to the production channel, the app stopped working. It didn't even load, it crashed in the splash.

What we did to solve the problem, was to clean the package, delete the Bin and Obj folders in the project, recompile again and publish directly to the production channel rather than putting it in the beta channel.

This is a really big problem since it brings stability problems to our app and we cannot determine the problem

-Edit-

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
  at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzbz.<init> (Unknown Source)
  at com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions.fromResource (Unknown Source)
  at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp (Unknown Source)
  at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate (Unknown Source)
  at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo (ContentProvider.java:1748)
  at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo (ContentProvider.java:1723)
  at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo (Unknown Source)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider (ActivityThread.java:5301)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders (ActivityThread.java:4896)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication (ActivityThread.java:4836)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600 (ActivityThread.java:163)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1423)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:148)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5585)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:730)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:620)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass (BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:511)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:469)
```

Comment: what is the crash log?